# after-directory is not loaded

Tags: vimscript, vimrc

To overwrite some formatoptions provided by my plugins I made `~/.vim/after/final.vim` file and add this location to my $RUNTIMEPATH by putting these lines just after (vundle) plugins in my .vimrc.

```
set rtp-=~/.vim/after 
set rtp+=~/.vim/after
```

I check if it's OK by:

```
:set rtp?
```

It is OK. ~/.vim/after is at the the end of the list.

According to the `:h after-directory` all *.vim files under ~/.vim/after should be loaded as a plugins.

It doesn't work. When I type

```
:scriptnames
```

there is nothing from my ~/.vim/after folder. What is going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you don't need to add `~/.vim/after/` to `runtimepath` as it's already part of the default value.

Second, the content of `~/.vim/after/` is supposed to match the structure found in `/usr/share/vim/vim7x/` and `~/.vim/` so, for your `final.vim` to be sourced like a plugin, you only need to put it where it belongs:

```
 ~/.vim/after/plugin/final.vim
```

See `:help 'runtimepath'`.

Comment: … but I'm not sure *why* you would need to do this.

Comment: :h 'runtimepath' shows default situation. In my case somehow ~/.vim/after was not present in runtimepath. When I added one line: set rtp+=~/.vim/after , it was not at the end of list.

Comment: Thanks! I need it because my formatoption=... , hlsearch, scrool=... and others are overwriten by Plugins. After your solution I got an "Error detected after processing /home/me/.vim/after/plugin/final.vim". Inside final.vim there are simple vimrc commands. Shouldn't it be in another folder? Where?

Comment: Show us the errors and the content of `final.vim` and `vimrc`. And investigate why `after/` is not in `&rtp`.

Comment: [github.com/UncleGoogle/vim]. final.vim is in .vim/after. 
EDIT: I've just realize that sth was automatically generated in final.vim I don't understand why, but I deleted this and now its ok. I'm adding also :scriptnames output -> interesting thing is despite all of my effords airline-plugin is loaded even after final.vim. Sneaky guy.